# Spring Boot scheduler Concurrency

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, azure, microservices, cloud-foundry

I have written a scheduler in java spring boot application, which run after every 300 ms and I want to deploy this jar to 2 Data center of PCF.

When I deploy the scheduler run twice. How can i restrict it to run 1nce at a time either by DC1 or by DC2.

I want it to run some time by DC1 or by DC2, reason behind that is if DC1 is down, application should not go down

Can some 1 plz suggest here?

Comment: Sounds like a job for a message queue. Have both instances consume messages from the *same* queue to trigger your processing(RabbitMq does this nicely with a Topic Exchange). Externalise your scheduler to be another service and have it put a message on the queue when you want your application to execute. Only one instance of your application can consume the message and so no more duplication. If either application goes down the other will consume the message (assuming they don't both go down!)

Comment: @jeremyt no we are not using any queue.. We are reading the data from oracle and manipulating the data and sending sms to users. no queue has been used here

Comment: I get that you don't *have* a message queue, but I think you're going to *need* one if you want to avoid every instance of your application doing the same thing.

Comment: @jeremyt any idea will shedlock solve this problem?

Comment: Sounds like as good an approach as any. I find these guys do excellent tutorials: https://www.baeldung.com/shedlock-spring